# Putting values in error.getModel in onBindAndValidate

Tags: java, validation, spring

I want to add some data to model if there wasn't any validation errors. I thought I could do this in onBindAndValidate, where I have the access to error object, which contains model:

```
errors.getModel().putAll(map);
```

I also tried to put values one by one using `put(key, value)` but without success.

What can I do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can do this after validation in processFinish:

```
return showPage(request, errors, getCurrentPage(request))
       .addAllObjects(map);
```

Answer (score 1):

You cannot directly add data to BindException's model. The reason you're not able to do:

```
errors.getModel().putAll(map);
```

is because *errors.getModel()* creates and returns new map each time you call it. So in your onBindAndValidate example, you're getting a new model from the BindException object, adding your data to the model, and then throwing it away. In your second example, you're adding the data to a model and then returning it.

Other common usage when using BindException's model from controller methods would look like this:

```
Map errorModel = errors.getModel();
errorModel.putAll(otherMap);
return new ModelAndView("viewName", errorModel );
```

See also: [BindException#getModel()](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.0.8/api/org/springframework/validation/BindException.html#getModel())